# how can use just one size drawable png file for different devices?

Tags: android, animation, png, drawable

I want to make a png animation in android studio. It needs many png files to make transition animation in android. For example i created a animation like this:

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/abrisham_lips_00000" android:duration="34"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/abrisham_lips_00001" android:duration="34"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/abrisham_lips_00002" android:duration="34" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/abrisham_lips_00003" android:duration="34" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/abrisham_lips_00004" android:duration="34" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/abrisham_lips_00005" android:duration="34" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/abrisham_lips_00006" android:duration="34" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/abrisham_lips_00007" android:duration="34" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/abrisham_lips_00008" android:duration="34" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/abrisham_lips_00009" android:duration="34" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/abrisham_lips_00010" android:duration="34" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/abrisham_lips_00011" android:duration="34" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/abrisham_lips_00012" android:duration="34" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/abrisham_lips_00013" android:duration="34" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/abrisham_lips_00014" android:duration="34" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/abrisham_lips_00015" android:duration="34" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/abrisham_lips_00016" android:duration="34" />
</animation-list>
```

As android drawable images need to have 5 different sizes:

> drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi

I am afraid that I will get many memory and file size errors in the application, so i need to use just one size of standard images for different android devices with different dpi.

Is it possible or not? Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but not recommended. If you only provide one size, that size will be used (it would have to be in the generic drawable folder), but the image will be scaled up or down, leading to fuzziness.

Have you considered an animated vector drawable?